# Three.js hdr bloom

Tags: three.js

I want to do an HDR glow, I found one example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom.html

But this is not exactly what I need, I can not properly adjust the glow, for example, for effects, it's necessary that they brightly shine.

The option to create a separate scene and about taking brightness there, but this is not the same, (rgb) range is too small for this.

There are options how it can be done?

If for example in the shaders themselves to specify the brightness of the pixel manually, then how can I get the whole result then? As for example (depth map)